# Error message not getting in WSO2 API manger 1.9?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.9 and getting error message as follows while call API with invalid token

```
{"fault":{"code":900901,"message":"Invalid Credentials","description":"Access     failure for API: /api/example/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 with key: 7d717ebecbafce1d324c9fafc2ffb53a8. Make sure your have given the correct access token"}}
```

Here i have send a dummy body to the API,but my end point is expecting 1.4 size body.If i call my API with actual body (size is 1.4 MB as per the project requirement) i am getting time out error instead of error message .For the valid token API is working fine  without any issue .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The given error comes when you have given an invalid token since it is an Invalid Authentication. Therefore what you have got is correct. Please check the error codes in APIM 1.9.0 in this documentation [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Error+Handling).

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Error+Handling) [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Error+Handling][1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Error+Handling)

Comment: Rigth ,I am getting this error while access API with with invalid token ,But If i call same API with same token  including large size data (request body) then i am not getting error message i am getting time out response .

Comment: Any size limit for request body  ?